# Como mostrar el resultado del metodo show en Ruby

Tags: ruby

Tengo un problema al llamar al método show, este debería mostrar la lista de los items en el carrito de compra, pero obtengo un string vacío como resultado.

```
class ShoppingCart

  def initialize
    @items = {:apple => 10, :oranges => 5 , :grapes => 15, :banana => 20, :watermelon => 50}
    @cost_total = 0
  end

  def add_item_to_cart(item)
    @cost_total += @items[item]
  end

  def show
    puts "#{@items[].each}"
  end

  def cost
    puts "#{@cost_total}"
  end

end

=begin
class Discounts
  def discounts_apple(item)
    if item(:apple) == 2
    end

  end
  =end

  cart = ShoppingCart.new

  cart.add_item_to_cart(:apple)
  cart.add_item_to_cart(:banana)
  cart.add_item_to_cart(:banana)

  #cart.show
  #1 apple: 10$
  #2 bananas: 40$
  cart.show
  cart.cost
```

Comment: Te sugiero ser mas especifico en la pregunta ya que no se puede comprender correctamente cual es el problema.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis: `puts "#{@items[].each}"`, pero no has especificado que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente.

Comment: ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0):

El metodo show esta llamando al metodo each el cual inicia una iteración pero no le indicas que hacer con la información en este caso mostrarla, para obtener la lista según indicas en los comentarios deberías cambiarlo por esto :

```
def show
  @items.map{|key, value| puts "#{key}" : "#{value}"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar el número de elementos añadidos al carrito debes tener constancia de todos los que has añadido. Es por ello que te aconsejo utilizar una nueva variable para guardarlos:

```
def initialize
  @items = {:apple => 10, :oranges => 5 , :grapes => 15, :banana => 20, :watermelon => 50}
  @cart = Hash.new(0)
  @cost_total = 0
end
```

`@cart` es un hash cuyas nuevas claves, tienen un valor por defecto de `0`. De esta forma, en `add_item_to_cart` puedes añadir un elemento al carrito si no existe, pero si existe, incrementa en uno la cantidad:

```
def add_item_to_cart(item)
  @cart[item] += 1
  @cost_total += @items[item]
end
```

Para mostrar el carrito se puede hacer algo tal que así:

```
def show
  @cart.each do |item, cantidad|
    puts "#{cantidad} #{item}: #{cantidad * @items[item]}$"
  end
end
```

Se recorre el carrito de la compra, para mostrar cada item, junto con su cantidad y el precio (nº de items * valor de item). Al ejecutar esto:

```
cart = ShoppingCart.new
cart.add_item_to_cart(:apple)
cart.add_item_to_cart(:banana)
cart.add_item_to_cart(:banana)
cart.show
```

Obtenemos:

```
1 apple: 10$
2 banana: 40$
```

**PD:** Como extra, una forma más "rubista" para calcular el coste total, sería utilizar un método que te devuelva el precio en vez de utilizar una variable. ¿Cuál es la ventaja? Bueno, si en un futuro se quisiera añadir un nuevo método que permitiese al cliente quitar un item del carrito, sería mucho más fácil actualizar el precio correcto:

```
def cost
  @cart.inject(0) { |sum, (k,v)| sum + v * @items[k] }
end
```

A primera vista, ¿parece un método muy raro no? [`inject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) te permite realizar operaciones aritméticas con los datos. En este caso, el objetivo es sumar el precio de todos los items. `sum` inicialmente vale `0`, y a él se le va sumando la cantidad de items del carrito multiplicado por su valor, donde `k` y `v` son la clave y el valor de `@cart`.